# Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to stack parameters on demand?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a setting or plugin that allows me to alt+enter and have intellij stack parameters on separate lines?

Would also be nice to have the oposite, to un-stack parameters, though this can already be easily done with ctrl+shift+j...

Comment: There is wrapping configuration for method call arguments, but it will work only if the line exceeds certain limit. You should probably [submit a new request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and provide the code samples for what you want (before/after).